# How to open Camera in Portrait Mode using OpenCV in Android Application

Tags: android, opencv, camera

I am using **OpveCV 2.4.7 library** When i use **OpenCV in Android Application** for open Camera then it shows the camera in Landscape mode. I tried by setting Activity Orientation to Portrait mode, but still it is not showing camera in full screen, **is their any way to open camera in Portrait mode in Android using OpenCV Library**

*Currently I am getting following screen default In android using OpvenCV Library*

[image: This is screenshot of default camera view in Landscape Mode of Activity in Android]

*I need full screen camera view in Portrait mode but i am getting this*

[image: This is screenshot of default camera view in Portrait Mode of Activity in Android]

I have tried Matrix transformation but i need to set Native Camera Parameters , i am using OpenCV to open camera so i can't directly access the camera. I have used following code

```
    mOpenCvCameraView=(CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.image_manipulations_activity_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) { }
Add following lines:

```
   // 3 statements to rotate camera
    Mat rotImage = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(new Point(mRgba.cols() / 2,
            mRgba.rows() / 2), 270, 1.0);
    Imgproc.warpAffine(mRgba, mRgba, rotImage, mRgba.size());
    Imgproc.warpAffine(mGray, mGray, rotImage, mRgba.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible because openCV deos not provides direct camera control to you , you need to **modify** the opven CV library class **CameraBridgeViewBase**

Comment: What modification has to be made ? could you please give me hint ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Make a JavaCamResView class which extends JavaCameraView of OPENCV. The you get camera Controls. 
     import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
                import java.lang.reflect.Method;
                import java.util.List;

```
            import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
            import org.opencv.core.Size;


            import android.content.Context;
            import android.hardware.Camera;
            import android.util.AttributeSet;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.MenuItem;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            public class JavaCamResView extends JavaCameraView {

                public JavaCamResView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                    super(context, attrs);

                }

                public List<Camera.Size> getResolutionList() {
                    return  mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                }

                public void setResolution(Camera.Size resolution) {
                    disconnectCamera();
                    connectCamera((int)resolution.width, (int)resolution.height);
                }

                public void setFocusMode (Context item, int type){

                    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

                    List<String> FocusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();

                    switch (type){
                        case 0:
                            if (FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO))
                                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(item, "Auto Mode not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO))
                                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(item, "Continuous Mode not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_EDOF))
                                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_EDOF);
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(item, "EDOF Mode not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if (FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED))
                                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED);
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(item, "Fixed Mode not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            if (FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY))
                                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY);
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(item, "Infinity Mode not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            if (FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO))
                                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO);
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(item, "Macro Mode not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }

                    mCamera.setParameters(params);
                }

                public void setFlashMode (Context item, int type){

                    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                    List<String> FlashModes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();

                    switch (type){
                        case 0:
                            if (FlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO))
                                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(item, "Auto Mode not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (FlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF))
                                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(item, "Off Mode not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (FlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON))
                                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(item, "On Mode not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if (FlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_RED_EYE))
                                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_RED_EYE);
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(item, "Red Eye Mode not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            if (FlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH))
                                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(item, "Torch Mode not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }

                    mCamera.setParameters(params);
                }

                public Camera.Size getResolution() {

                    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

                    Camera.Size s = params.getPreviewSize();
                    return s;
                }

                public void zoomIn()
                {

                    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                    if (params.isZoomSupported()) {
                        final int maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();
                        int currentZoomLevel = params.getZoom();
                        Log.i("max ZOOM ", "is " + maxZoomLevel);
                        Log.i("current ZOOM ", "is " + currentZoomLevel);

                        if(currentZoomLevel < maxZoomLevel){
                            currentZoomLevel++;
                            params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                            mCamera.setParameters(params);

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.i("ZOOM " , "NOT Supported");

                    }

                }

                public int getExposure()
                {
                    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                    return params.getExposureCompensation();
                }
                public int getMinExposure()
                {
                    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                    return params.getMinExposureCompensation();
                }
                public int getMaxExposure()
                {
                    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                    return params.getMaxExposureCompensation();
                }
                public void setExposure(int exposure)
                {
                        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                        params.setExposureCompensation(exposure);
                        mCamera.setParameters(params);

                    }

                public void setZoom(int zoom_value)
                {

                    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                    if (params.isZoomSupported()) {
                        final int maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();
                        int currentZoomLevel = params.getZoom();


                      //  Log.i("CAMERA_SETTING", "Exposure setting = " + params.get("exposure"));
                        Log.i("CAMERA_SETTING", "Current Exposure Compansation = " + params.getExposureCompensation());
                        Log.i("CAMERA_SETTING", "min Exposure Compansation = " + params.getMinExposureCompensation());
                        Log.i("CAMERA_SETTING", "Max Exposure Compansation = " + params.getMaxExposureCompensation());
                        Log.i("CAMERA_SETTING", "White Balance setting = " + params.get("whitebalance"));
                        Log.i("CAMERA_SETTING", "Supported White Balance Modes:" + params.get("whitebalance-values"));
                        if(zoom_value < maxZoomLevel){
                            params.setZoom(zoom_value);
                            mCamera.setParameters(params);

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.i("ZOOM " , "NOT Supported");

                    }

                }
                public void zoomOut()
                {

                    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                    if (params.isZoomSupported()) {

                        int currentZoomLevel = params.getZoom();
                        Log.i("current ZOOM ", "is " + currentZoomLevel);

                        if(currentZoomLevel > 0 ){
                            currentZoomLevel--;
                            params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                            mCamera.setParameters(params);

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.i("ZOOM " , "NOT Supported");

                    }

                }

                public void getPictureSize()
                {
                    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                    List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                    Camera.Size mSize;
                    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                        Log.i("CAMERA_SIZE", "Available resolution: "+size.width+" "+size.height);
                        mSize = size;
                    }
                    params.setPictureSize(1280 , 768);
                    mCamera.setParameters(params);
                }

                public void getOptimalPreviewSize( int w, int h) {
                    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
                    double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

                    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                    List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

                    if (sizes == null) return;

                    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
                    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

                    int targetHeight = h;

                    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
                        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
                        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                            optimalSize = size;
                            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                        }
                    }

                    if (optimalSize == null) {
                        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                                optimalSize = size;
                                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i("CAMERA_SIZE", "Optimal Size: "+optimalSize.width+" "+optimalSize.height);
                }

                public void changeOrientation() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
                    Method rotateMethod;
                    rotateMethod = android.hardware.Camera.class.getMethod("setDisplayOrientation", int.class);
                    rotateMethod.invoke(mCamera, 90);
                }




            }
```