# OpenCV Android Portrait Mode Full Screen setting

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, android-camera

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261612/how-to-open-camera-in-portrait-mode-using-opencv-in-android-application)  Question is alreday asked but i am also facing the same problem I resolved it by rotating it by 90 degree but I am just asking if someone has proper solution since this question dates back to one and half years ago

Also, if I use completely NATIVE openCV will this problem be eliminated?
There is nice openCV Sample Native Camera

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();

    Mat rotImage = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(new Point(mRgba.cols() / 2,
            mRgba.rows() / 2), 90, 1.0);

    Imgproc.warpAffine(mRgba, mRgba, rotImage, mRgba.size());

    Imgproc.warpAffine(mGray, mGray, rotImage, mRgba.size());
```

This will rotate the view, but it will not be full screen. I am facing the same problem and haven't found a solution so far.