# Detect faces in portrait mode using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, camera

I have the problem of using OpenCV 2.4.11 in portrait and make the recognition of faces. I used the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380553/how-to-use-opencv-face-detection-in-portrait-using-byte-data-from-onpreviewfra) but does not work, the screen goes black and the log shows these errors ... how can I fix it and use the camera more OpenCV in portrait recognize faces?

> E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.dims == 2 &&
>   info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols)
>   in void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass,
>   jlong, jobject, jboolean), file
>   /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp,
>   line 97
>
> Utils.matToBitmap() throws an exception:
>   /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:97:
>   error: (-215) src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows &&
>   info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols in function void
>   Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong,
>   jobject, jboolean)

I checked [this means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261612/how-to-open-camera-in-portrait-mode-using-opencv-in-android-application), but I can not understand where to change the orientation to portrait to have the camera preview in fullscreen and recognize faces.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. On this [page](http://blog.f11labz.com/open-cv-preview-in-portrait-mode-in-android/) give an example of how to customize the OpenCV camera class and with this recognition and both the camera preview in portrait work.